# Error During IMPDP in oracle database 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, oracle-12c, oracle-11g

I create Dump file with EXPDP command in oracle database 11gR2 with operating system Oracle Linux 6.7

**EXPDP Command:**

```
expdp hmis/pass directory=MY_DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=12c_db.dmp logfile=12c_db.log COMPRESSION=ALL FULL=Y
```

Now when I run IMPDP command in oracle database 12c with operating system Oracle Linux 7.7 then I am getting errors. I have CDB and PDB database in 12c

**IMPDP Command:**

```
impdp c##app/pass directory=MY_DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=12c_db.dmp logfile=12c_db.log FULL=Y
```

**Error:**

```
ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"HMIS"."TEMP_WE_TEST" failed to create with error:
ORA-01918: user 'HMIS' does not exist

ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"APEX_030200"."WWV_FLOW_WORKSHEET_STICK" failed to create with error:
ORA-01918: user 'APEX_030200' does not exist

ORA-39083: Object type TABLE:"SYSMAN"."MGMT_GENSVC_AVAIL_BEACONS" failed to create with error:
ORA-01918: user 'SYSMAN' does not exist
```

How to solve this problem
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory:

```
ORA-01918: user 'XXXXXX' does not exist
```

Look at the log output for your `expdp` execution. If it does not contain the following:

```
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/USER
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/SYSTEM_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/ROLE_GRANT
Processing object type SCHEMA_EXPORT/DEFAULT_ROLE
```

... then the users & grants were not exported in the first place, and so were not created when importing.

`FULL=Y` does not solve the problem when the users were not exported in the first  place.

Check that the exporting user, `hmis` has the `CREATE USER` grant, then re-export the data.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create the user that you imported, and if you want to change the name of your schema; set in the configuration:

```
remapremap_schema
remap_tablespace
```

I hope those optiones are useful for you, regards!